# size of a dictionary object in Bytes

Tags: c#, java, memory-management, dictionary, garbage-collection

I would like to know the size of a dictionary item in bytes.How could I do that? Is there any predefined method? I saw a similar question being answered saying to get the difference using GC.TotalMemory method. But here I cannot Gc.KeepAlive the object. Please advice. The problem of calculating the difference before and after the usage of the dictionary is not possible as the total memory would not only include that dictionary's memory but also memory of several other threads.Please provide an alternative way for this.

Comment: You should give more information. Why do you need the size? Are the objects serializable?

Comment: I need the size as I need to optimize the code because of high memory consumption.For that I need to know if my dictionary is efficient. And the objects are not serializable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
long StopBytes = 0;

// Declare your dictionnary
Dictionary<string, int> myDictionary;

// Get total memory before create your dictionnary
long StartBytes = System.GC.GetTotalMemory(true);

// Initialize your dictionnary
myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();

// Get total memory after create your dictionnary
StopBytes = System.GC.GetTotalMemory(true);

// This ensure a reference to object keeps object in memory
GC.KeepAlive(myFoo); 

// Calcul the difference , and that all :-)
MessageBox.Show("Size is " + ((long)(StopBytes - StartBytes)).ToString());
```

More information here -> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mab/archive/2006/04/24/582666.aspx

Comment: There is a problem.I could do like this, but when the dictionary is created and items are added there are so many other threads also running on the same time.So is there an alternative method where I don't have to calculate the total memory before and after? Because that total memory would include several other thread's memory apart from the dictioanry's memory.Please advice